# Finding id of taxonomy by name in custom post type

Tags: taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `book-list`.
I get the name of the post type category from the link by `$_GET['w_year']` correctly.
I need to get the ID of that category name

I'm not inside a post or anything. just need the id for knowing on what year the user want to work.

Comment: You want to get the name of a category by its id?

Comment: Or you want to get the id of a taxonomy by its name? Because I don't know what good it will do you.

Comment: I need the id

I found something that works:

$w_year = $_GET['w_year'];
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax_type_key => $taxonomy ) {
    // If term object is returned, break out of loop. (Returns false if there's no object)
    if ( $term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $w_year , $taxonomy ) ) {
        break;
    }
}
$catid = $term_object->term_id;

Answer (score 0):

@Gil, your solution in comment seems to be excellent!
I just modified a small part to be sure not to have a PHP warning on execution.

```php
$w_year = $_GET['w_year'];

$catid = '';
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) { 
    if ( $term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $w_year , $taxonomy ) ) {
        if ( !empty($term_object->term_id) ) {
            $catid = $term_object->term_id; 
            break; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-)